# AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed the Android Eclipse Plugin and the Android SDK from Google yesterday. I open the AVD Manager window by going to `Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager`. I then click "New" and am presented with the "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" window. The problem is, I can't get the "OK" button to not be greyed out. I choose Nexus 7 from "Device", I give the AVD a name, I choose "Android 4.2 API Level 17" as the target. And no matter what I do for the rest of the settings, the "OK" button continues to be greyed out. I am not presented with any errors. Any idea as to what I may be missing and why the window would not allow me to proceed by clicking "OK"?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, but as per @Ralgha's answer, I've already installed `ARM EABI v7a System Image`. My CPU/ABI dropdown list is actually empty; there's nothing for me to select. Any thoughts?

Comment: You may want to try using different API versions. I went ahead and installed every API version that I could. Depending on the API version I choose, I have the ability to choose different CPU emulators. I have also installed the Intel HAXM which made a WORLD of difference when running the emulator.

Comment: I've installed multiple API versions (not all of them, but all the 4.x ones) and there's still nothing in my CPU/ABI list. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I can vouch for dragonridingsorceress. same story here. i'm using a mac book pro, with Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: @DavidT. Try selecting a Device from the first dropdown. It will autofill everything but Name for you. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003009/android-virtual-device-manager-cannot-create-avd/14207730#14207730

Comment: @dragonridingsorceress hahah, i figured it out after a bit of frustrating. thanks!!

Comment: Hello @dragonridingsorceress, would you mind sharing what solved your problem for others to see? It may help someone else, thanks!

Comment: Hi purlogic, as I explained in my comment above to @DavidT., I had to select a preset Device from the first dropdown.

Comment: I was having this issue when my AVD name had a space in it.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You either haven't selected a CPU/ABI target in the dropdown below the target, or you haven't installed a system image.  Open your SDK manager and ensure that you've installed `ARM EABI v7a System Image` under the Android 4.2 section.

Comment: I went to Windows -> Android SDK Manager and installed the ARM EABI v7a System Image.

Comment: Don't forget to restart Eclipse (if you are using it) after installation.

Comment: After installation if ARM EABI v7a System Image, don't forgot to restart Eclipse. And if it is already installed then please make sure your device name does not contain _"spaces"_ like (Nexus 4). If your name has space the "OK" button will remain disabled.

Comment: to add to it, it doesn't like single letter in Name field :)

Comment: I also doesn't like spaces.

Answer (score 25):

I had trouble creating an AVD.

Either:

- re-start eclipse after installing SDK versions from the SDK manager, or
- you should run the "AVD Manager.exe" outside of Eclipse

Comment: Yes, I restarted eclipse after install SDK version,  then it showed up on AVD manager. :)

Answer (score 22):

First, make sure you don't have spaces (or other illegal characters like '+','=','/',etc) in the "AVD Name" field. Spaces broke it for me.

Comment: It would be nice if they specified that as a requirement

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, although all required packages were installed. I closed down Eclipse, ran monitor.bat in the \android-sdks\tools\ folder, opened the AVD Manager from there, and I was able the create virtual devices here.

Comment: This worked for me when I had the problem adding Virtual Devices

Answer (score 9):

you need to avoid spaces in the AVD name.
 & Select the "Skin" option.

Answer (score 6):

Try to create an AVD with the `monitor.bat` in the `tools-folder`, that worked out for me!

Answer (score 5):

Another thing that tripped me up: the "Name" field must be a single word and must not have spaces!

Comment: This was it for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Had the exact same trouble... loading the ARM EABI v7a System Image worked for me too. Thanks very much.

I had previously seen on the Android SDK manager that a system image with the same name (ARM EABI v7a System Image) WAS installed on my system for a more recent SDK (Android 4.2). Consequently I thought it would negate the need to install the earlier Android 2.2 SDK ARM image, but apparently not.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  Your answer is a bit a "me, tooish".  Generally on SO, "me tooish" type stuff is discouraged for answers.  It might be better to put something like this in the comments.

Comment: I agree entirely. I planned to add this as a comment to the answer above, but as a new contributor, I don't have enough reputation to do that yet (Current:1, needed:50). I better get busy!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but now I got it: Check which API you are selecting and for that **API version** is **CPU/ABI** available or not. If it's available then your work is done. Select the device according to the windows supporting it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open up your SDK Manager and make sure everything is installed, especially System Image. After that will be alright!

Comment: Hello, lili and welcome to stackoverflow! Did you see the other comments/answersunder? It seems this was already suggested and this is not the reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you have changed the SDK Path somehow it will not be able to find the SDKs you installed even though it is listing them fine.

I solved by openig Android SDK Manager and in that dialog choosing the menu Tools -> Manage AVDs. And when you open Manage AVDs directly from the toolbar of Eclipse you should Refresh to see the AVD you created.

Answer (score 2):

I actually hit on this problem a week ago.  The issue had to do with not using an updated Eclipse version of the Android SDK plugin with the latest version of the SDK.  It was a fun problem overall, but it disappeared as soon as I updated it.

I had even updated the AVD images and no luck.  Apparently the old plugin cannot see the new image layout or something.  This is for version 22.3 of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

On Kubuntu 12.04, Eclipse Kepler, ADT installed, I experienced the same symptoms. The ARM EABI v7a System Image was already installed. The way out was to run the tool from the command line, then it did not complain. I guess a restart of eclipse could have done the trick but I am not sure any more if I tried dit or not.

Answer (score 1):

I opened monitor.bat in android-sdks\tools and started the device manager there and I was able to create the AVD.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @iTech This is an answer to the question, it's just a poor one. ond: please expand upon your answers more in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Launching the AVD Manager from Visual Studio 2015 resolved this issue for me.**

I had (a lot of packages) **all the required packages installed** but hadn't used them for some time & had **issues detecting** them in the SDK manager.
I attempted all the solutions provided above to no avail, including running the AVD after running the monitor.bat file in 'android/sdk/tools'.

I then launched the AVD from VS in 'Tools->Android->Android Emulator Manager' and it detected both 'Google APIs Intel Atom x86' & the ARM EABI v7a system Images *right off the bat!*

Target is set to API Level 23.

Answer (score -2):

If you are having AVD creation problems, just try to put it inside a new folder (eclipse, android sdk, avd) and then you just run it and it should work. Just open Eclipse in that folder and run as usual