# Android AVD, No Target Selected

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create an AVD, but after selecting the target also, it is showing "No Target Selected".

Comment: Hi please can u upload screen shot of create AVD window so that we can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)

Answer (score 8):

to solve the problem. install one of CPU System Images. for example: ARM EABI v7a System Image

Comment: What is the `CPU System Images`?

Answer (score 7):

This problem has been solve in another thread: [AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)

To solve the problem:

- You need to install the CPU system image. e.g. open your SDK manager and install ARM EABI v7a System Image under the Android 4.2 section.
- If you are using Eclipse, restart it.(I stuck here ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must install one CPU on the android ADV and then restart your Eclipse. You can open this tool by running `android sdk` from the commandline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its may be happening because the Device which you have selected may not be able to support the selected Target. So change your target according to device specification.

Because Some of the low resolution devices doesn't support the higher API level targets.

Answer (score 1):

May be while creating your application you may set target as different like 4.2.2 and actually you may be creating avds of different version like 1.5 . check out that. if so create avd as of your target.
If you cannot you have to update avd version from sdk manager.

Answer (score 1):

In my case on Ubuntu, I did install the **system image** from the **android sdk manager** for that specific **API** but still had the same issue after restarting eclipse. What I did was the following:

For some reason, in the **sdk/system-images/android-xx** directory, sub-folders with system images (armeabi-v7a and x86) were placed within **default** directory. I just moved them up a level into **andorid-xx** directory, restart eclipse and done. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even download the AVD at the first place?