# Can't Create AVD "No Target selected"

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Cannot create AVD - I searched previous answers and I do have ARM EABI v7 installed.
Additional detail - I installed ARM appropriate for the API level.  Still no target available.
Image of error and SDK manager:

[image]

Well.... I cannot answer my own question as I dont have the reputation so I have to edit the original question.

The solution is a classic, I rebooted and it worked.  I literally "turned it off and on again".

insert forehead slap here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android AVD, No Target Selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374119/android-avd-no-target-selected)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solve in another thread: AVD Manager - [Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)

To solve the problem:

- You need to install the CPU system image. e.g. open your SDK manager and install ARM EABI v7a System Image under the Android 4.2 section.
- If you are using Eclipse, restart it.(I stuck here ;)