# OK button in "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" dialog does not do anything

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Tried to create an AVD from the eclipse environment in the following steps:

1. Click Window/Android Virtual Device Manager. This brings up the "Android Virtual Device Manager" dialog.
2. In the dialog, click "New...". This brings up the "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" dialog.
3. Fill out the fields in this dialog, then click the OK button.
4. But the OK button doesn't do anything. The "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" dialog still stays up and nothing is created.

Answer (score 82):

you need to avoid spaces in the AVD name. Put underscore instead and the OK button will become active :)

Comment: Star this if you agree this is stupid: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75547&thanks=75547&ts=1409538967

Comment: @phsource There are many things that can cause the button to be grayed out, and none of them give a warning. Extremely annoying.

Comment: @DavidB: I played with Xamarin months ago and now we are trying to set a React-Native environment... I believe I am not alone in the feeling that these mobile development platforms give us the feeling we are developing   some 20 years ago. All sort of bugs related to wrong paths, unexpected character here/there... So much bugs, absence of essential documentation... I don't get it.

Comment: The answer does not make sense, or at least does not go in hand with the  [how-to doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html). **"Device Name: Name of the hardware profile. The name can contain uppercase or lowercase letters, numbers from 0 to 9, periods (.), underscores (_), parentheses ( () ), and spaces. The name of the file storing the hardware profile is derived from the hardware profile name."**

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Looks like this is a bug reported since ADT 22.6. Please find more information in this post:

[Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-from-eclipse-ok-button-works)

I was actually able to reproduce the same issue inside of my environment. As a workaround I was able to open the AVD manager outside of Eclipse by using the following command in terminal:

`android-sdk-location/tools/android avd`

After opening the AVD manager outside of eclipse it let me create the device successfully. Please note you will have to restart Eclipse once you create the device in order for it to show up in the list of usable devices.

Please look at this similar post for some more suggestions if needed:

[AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)

**EDIT: Update to latest AVD manager and this issue should go away**

Comment: There is no android avd file in that location in the current bundle

Comment: Thank you. Even in the latest AVD manager, I had the same problem and starting AVD manager directly solved it.

Answer (score 14):

It's not a bug! I solved the problem by deleting the gap between the letters of the AVD name which I'm going to make!

Whenever I add a space in the AVD name, the "ok" button is disabled!

Comment: There is nothing is to downvote this answer. This is what the problem I faced with..

Comment: I had this same problem. Thnaks for sharing, I would have never suspected the problem was there

Comment: my OK button is still greyed out despite the name having no spaces (BTW, FTR, I didn't downvote you)

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It's bad design.

Comment: can't believe they still didn't fix this stupid problem.

Comment: I would consider it a bug - a UX bug. Vote for the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75547

Answer (score 9):

Using the "Create Device" didn't work for me, however using "Clone" from an existing device and just modifying all of the values worked fine.
Spaces were allowed in the name as well.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to find a solution by installing the System Images for the Android version I was looking to emulate.

Open up the Android SDK Manager -> Android 4.4.2 -> Check ARM EABI v7a System Image and Intel x86 Atom System Image -> Click Install Packages.

[image]

Reopen the AVD Manager and create a new virtual device.

Comment: this is the main problem here not the spaces thing etc.

Answer (score 5):

Even i faced the same problem, installing ARM EABI v7a System Image solved. try this "Open your SDK manager and ensure that you've installed ARM EABI v7a System Image"

Comment: yep, jaalgar's answer links to that one too, it's for when the OK button is greyed out and the CPU/ABI field (just below the target field in the 'android virtual device manager' window) says something about something being not installed. Had to restart eclipse after too.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't create a device then just clone it.

```
Open ADT Manger

Click on Device Definations

Double Tap on the device you want

Edit it and click on clone

Then create your device as you wish with low specifications.
```

You are done now

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, open the installed folder of the `android-sdk`.

It will be located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

then execute "AVD Manager.exe" directly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the skin drop down list is nothing, so you need to choose a skin.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you guys are using Windows OS
check if you have set the path for Java, platform tools and tools in environment variables.
Then logout and login once again. 
Generally in windows the environmental variables come into effect after that login

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete 'ALL' my old AVDs first, then OK button appeared and I was able to create new ones. Some old AVDs were built on old versions of android so i suspect this was causing conflict to AVD manager.

Answer (score 0):

Guys the issue has been solved, from ADT or Eclipse open the SDK Manager (Windows > SDK Manager) and then from the SDK Manager you can use Menu Tools > Manage AVDs and that will work to create AVDs as well to repair old AVDs.

Answer (score 0):

Another silly thing that makes the OK button disabled is using the same name for the Virtual machine. Every time you click the "Create AVD" button,from the "Device Definitions" tab, AVD manager fills in a name by default. I had created one such AVD earlier and wanted to try another configuration and had the OK button disabled because the name already was in use.

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate AVD Name also keeps the OK button disabled please check that as well

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and reinstalled Intel HAXM as I was using the Intel Atom image. After inputting all the settings the 'OK' button was still greyed out only after selecting 'Skin' field as 'No Skin' did it become active, so I guess you have to choose a skin, even if that means choosing 'No Skin'.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**My problem was solved by freeing disk space**.

I had some 2 GB free, and noticed that after closing the Add Virtual Device window there was a `red notification on the top-right corner of Android Studio`.

Clicked it, and it `showed a log message stating freeing disk space was required`.

I did it, and next time I tried adding a virtual device, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

you need `AVD Manager` so install SDK from [here](http://androidcode.ir/post/install-SDK-windows-android-lynda-%D9%86%D8%B5%D8%A8-%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B2),
then make `Android Virtual Device` where you install SDK, not in Eclips.

when you run Eclips you can see your AVD in windows->Android Virtual Device Manager.

later, you can add `system image`, `APIs`, ... in SDK, because this SDK isn't full.

Comment: Its also greyed out if you are in the middle of a deployment and haven't closed the project properly.  What a croc this stuff is ...