# AVD Manager, why can't I create an AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

For some reason, I cannot create an AVD. I went through [AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13959128/1896169) and attempted the solutions, and I also fiddled with the different settings in the manager, including changing the name to `Device`. I made sure that the system images are installed, and I followed the instructions for using the [Intel Atom](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213271). Why is the <kbd>OK</kbd> greyed out?

[image: Picture of the AVD Manager's "create new avd" that shows all the settings that are set]

I even ran the AVD Manager from eclipse, from the exe, and from monitor.bat

For reference, I did install the Atom's image:

[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @ChuongPham Windows 8.1

Comment: The RAM option should be okay then. Tried changing some of the other options, for example, VM Heap to 64, or even 128. Also, I'm assuming you have installed the Intel image successfully. Lastly, change, or add, these options to `eclipse.ini` file -Xms64m
-Xmx512m. Again, change `-Xms` value to 128 if required. These options give Eclipse a bit more grunt.

Comment: @ChuongPham Do I need to change those options before or after creating the AVD? Because I changed them in the AVD Manager and the OK button is still greyed out. And changing which CPU/ABI I use (ARM or Intel) doesn't un-grey it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. But if it does not work when you tried to modify it, then delete the AVD definition and re-create it. Also, I forgot to mention that if you change the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` directives, you'll need to restart Eclipse.

Comment: @ChuongPham I've re-done the AVD Definition many times (~4 times)

Comment: Also, I don't know if you know, but you MUST have exactly the same versions for both Android SDK and ADT. For example, if you have Android SDK v22.6.2, you must also have ADT v22.6.2. Mismatch versions can lead to many unforseen problems with Android. Also, Android currently does not support JDK v7. The best available, supportable JDK version is 1.6.45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, running the AVD via command line worked, but I couldn't check `Use Host GPU`. Thanks to [Rusher](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14718946#14718946) who got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213144/1896169 . See [Running Your App | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) for instructions on running via command line:

> From the command line, change directories to `<sdk>/tools/` and execute:
>
> `android avd`

In other words, typing this into command line should work:

```
cd whateverThePathToYourSDKIs/tools/

android avd
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only use either **Snapshot** or **Host GPU**.

**Snapshot** or **Host GPU** they can not be used simultaneously.

now try to start avd from avd manager.

Comment: This is a good answer... for a different question. Let me create on for you (or find one) so you can answer this there.

Comment: but avd started or not this time??

Comment: I ran it for Snapshot. It worked when I ran the AVD. Before, the AVD Manager didn't work.

Comment: so I think you got it? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617131/android-why-snapshots-and-gpu-are-mutually-exclusive

Comment: Umm, you know that I got your answer to the other question (I asked that one too).

Comment: so what about this? what is the right answer? can you elaborate ?

Comment: This is a good answer. But it is not **the** answer to this question. The answer I posted is **the** answer to this question, so in 2 days (ie when it will let me), I'll accept it.

Comment: sure.. and let me know.. because I'm curious too :) thanks bye.

Comment: so whats your view about this now? do you got anything important?