# Android Monitor.bat is not running

Tags: android, ddms

Hi I am not able to run monitor tool in Android.

I have tried downloading the sdk and also android-studio, but I am not able to download it in either of the cases.

I find the following error when I run monitor.bat

> Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine

DDM.bat works perfectly fine

Comment: Check that question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device). It's similar on yours.

Comment: Hmm For me monitor tools does not work at all, I am trying to figure out if I can increase the heap size and check for Java, any idea how to do it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my case,

I have changed monitor.ini file in tools/lib/monitor-x86 folder as below,

**-Xms256m**

**-Xmx512m**

I hope this tip is useful to you.

Comment: I had the same problem with Android Device Monitor in Android Studio and this solved it. Thanks.