# android device monitor not running in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ddms, android-2.2-froyo

The android device monitor in Android Studio is not running no matter how many times I click on it, there are no errors showing up or warnings.It's just not running, I don't know why this is happening  because I used to open it with no problems whatsoever. what could the problem be?? THe android sdk path is correct and the emulator is running and there are no errors in the code. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Monitor.bat is not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523107/android-monitor-bat-is-not-running)

Comment: try to open the device monitor from the command line and see the output. To run it your_path/Android/Sdk/tools/monitor

Answer (score 3):

Try using ALT + 6 to open the device monitor window, or are you saying that Android Studio is not finding your device?

Answer (score 0):

It takes an awfully lot of time for the ADM to finally appear. Just wait, do something else while it is opening.

Comment: I don't think so, I've been waiting for more than an hour, it used to start up in 10-15 minutes