# Eclipse - Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager Create Device does not work

Tags: android, eclipse, galaxy

I am following the steps to add a Samsung Galaxy S6 AVD from here:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

I create the device and see it on the Device Definitions list.

The problem is that once I create an AVD, the new device is not listed under the device dropdown.

Also if I close the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager window and reopen, the  Samsung Galaxy S6 device is no longer on the Device Definitions list.

I am using:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)

Comment: I have done just about everything on the AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device post and does not work.

The issue I am reporting is different.  I can create an AVD, it just wont remain, it disappears when ADV manager window is closed.